# Vuejs 2 Bootstrap 4beta navbar items are not showing

Tags: jquery, html, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, webpack-2

I'v created a project with vue-cli and added bootstrap 4-beta acording to its docs. Now all I got is a blank navbar even though the template I copied from the bootstrap page contains Items. Vuejs bootstrap and all it's dependencies are loaded correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="../assets/logo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Bootstrap
  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But all I got is: 
[navbar not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSliu.png)

[image]